# Get windows filename without extension in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get the file path in PostgreSQL.

I think a regular expression would probably be the best solution, but I have no knowledge on how to write those

> What I have `\\spfs1\stone\foo.txt`
>
> What I want `foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't actually know the path depth and all file names your looking for end with '.txt' the following should get what you want.

```
with parm(stg) as (select '\\spfs1\stone\foo.txt'::text)
select stg, substring(stg from '.*\\(.*)\.txt$') from parm;
```

What the pattern does:

- .*     look for any number of characters
- \\     followed by the character \
- (.*)   followed by any number of characters and capture those characters
- \.txt  followed by .txt
- $      end of line 
  Return the captured characters. Note: had file name been "foo.bar.txt" this would return "foo.bar".